# Regex in R to extract substring omitting last few chars?

Tags: r, regex

I have a dataframe that looks like

```
ID              Name
1     Super novaNOVA
2           ABCDABCD
3 The ATM MachineATM
4          AlaskaULA
5      StomrsvilleST
6           HikeHIKE
...
```

I want to leave the entries in the `Name` column the same but with the last chars in all caps removed. That is, I want it to look like

```
ID           Name
1      Super nova
2            ABCD
3 The ATM Machine
4          Alaska
5     Stomrsville
6            Hike
...
```

In the case of `ABCDABCD`, even though all the chars are in caps, I just half of it. Because `ABCD` just repeats itself, so I only need `ABCD`

How can I do this in R?

EDIT: `Super novaNOVA` should become `Super nova`, not `Supernova`

Comment: Shouldn't `Super novaNOVA` become `Super nova`?

Comment: yes, that was a typo. I changed it in my EDIT

Comment: What is the rule with `AlaskaULA`? I can only get `AlaskU` for now, to be consistent with other examples.

Comment: `AlaskaULA` has `ULA` as the ending in all caps. So it needs to be removed, leaving `Alaska`

Comment: Try `sub("[A-Z]{1,4}$", "", x)`. This does not check anything, just remove 1 to 4 uppercase ASCII letters at the end of the string.

Comment: That nearly every row correct. However, it converted `MooneMOONE` to `MooneM` instead of `Moone`. And for `ABCABC` it generated `AB` instead of `ABC`

Comment: Also, for `Laser (MD)L-MD` it generated `Laser (MD)L-` instead of `Laser (MD)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
x <- c("Super novaNOVA", "ABCDABCD", "The ATM MachineATM", "AlaskaULA", "StomrsvilleST", "HikeHIKE", "MooneMOONE", "ABCABC", "Laser (MD)L-MD")
sub("(?s)^(.*)(?i:\\1)$|[A-Z-]{1,4}$", "\\1", x, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [online R demo](http://ideone.com/MIaEG1) and an [online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9dyMQO/2).

If a string is composed of 2 duplicate parts, only 1 part is kept, the other is removed with `^(.*)(?i:\\1)$` OR 1 to 4 uppercase ASCII letters or `-` are removed.

**Details**:

- `(?s)` - a DOTALL modifier (in a PCRE regex, a `.` does not automatically match line break chars)
- `^` - start of a string
- `(.*)` - Group 1 capturing any 0+ chars as many as possible
- `(?i:\\1)` - a modifier group that matches the same text as in Group 1 in a case insensitive way
- `$` - end of string
- `|` - or
- `[A-Z-]{1,4}`  - 1 to 4 uppercase ASCII letters or `-` up to the...
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: That's almost what I wanted. I just noticed for the entry `Laser (MD)L-MD` it generated `Laser (MD)L-` instead of `Laser (MD)`

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not sure about the min or max number of Uppercased words, I suggest **[A-Z]*$**

```
x <- replicate(15, paste0(paste0(sample(letters,3), collapse = ""), paste0(sample(LETTERS,3), collapse = "")))
x
 [1] "pjnIKJ" "agjHGC" "pdaTSG" "lfcLEC" "ileGAC" "braKYE" "iruSQY" "aizPNR" "trpFPS" "zyoZKQ" "bmhCAE" "aorNCV" "fkeVYO" "naxLTV"
[15] "smeXZH"

gsub("[A-Z]*$", "", x)
 [1] "pjn" "agj" "pda" "lfc" "ile" "bra" "iru" "aiz" "trp" "zyo" "bmh" "aor" "fke" "nax" "sme"
x <- replicate(15, paste0(paste0(sample(letters,3), collapse = ""), paste0(sample(LETTERS,6), collapse = "")))
x
 [1] "rlfZYFDKT" "oauLJMIWT" "xvdDVNBFC" "wglBROVTN" "reqHGXEMC" "wtgXUFKTZ" "lewDLHOGA" "ujtYMATJH" "nldHQUZOT" "azdCQTWBR"
[11] "wjkYPOSNF" "lhvGZEJNV" "kjnKPCFUX" "tbaYTWQSL" "lwrPQHVFA"

gsub("[A-Z]*$", "", x)
"rlf" "oau" "xvd" "wgl" "req" "wtg" "lew" "ujt" "nld" "azd" "wjk" "lhv" "kjn" "tba" "lwr"
```